# Can I safely uncheck the Optimize Mac Storage check box after already stoping & starting upload?

Tags: mac, icloud

I tried to set up iCloud but didn't understand it would delete files from my computer. I freaked out and just tried to turn it off. After a few minutes (w/ very little even copied to iCloud) all the desktop files VANISHED. So, I turned it back on. All files came back!

Then I learned about the Optimize Mac Storage box! (I had it checked), So, I have unchecked that box, so I can keep the files on my computer also. BUT, now it is taking way too long to upload (I have 800GBs).

**Can I NOW turn it off and not fear the files disappearing again**, (since I have Optimize Mac Storage unchecked), or have I messed something up by trying to stop the process?

PS: For the moment I will let it continue to upload. (I do have enough room in my iCloud storage at 2TB). I do run Time Machine, so I don't fear losing my files (too much).

PPS: I found https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380459/9058 but it doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Comment: I did notice that of the two folders iCloud backs up (Desktop & Documents) The Documents one appears done. And I see those files on the iCloud web browser and still locally (with NO cloud icons). I'm assuming this is because I turned off Optimize Mac Storage and therefore it has left copies of all files locally. I suppose I just let the 800GB keep copying, maybe it just will take several days. I just don't want to see all the files vanish upon completion! (hoping this is just an irrational fear!).

Comment: Don't see why they should vanish, actually.

Comment: This article should give you all the necessary answers: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985

Comment: What happens when you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud
If you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud, a new Desktop and Documents folder is created in your home folder. You also have the option to keep a local copy of your files that are in iCloud Drive. If you keep a local copy of your files in iCloud Drive, they're copied to a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive) in your home folder. You can move any files that were in your iCloud Desktop and Documents to your new local Desktop and Documents. (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985)

Comment: But why did all the files disappear when I turned it off before and come back? This was very unnerving, and now I'm terrified about doing anything, but let it copy all 1.2 TBs to iCloud, which may take days. (about 10GB of the 1.2 have copied), Why would it have to copy anything to a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive) if the files are already on my computer? This is super confusing.

Comment: Most of my files have a cloud icon next to them, when I hover over it says "uploading." If I did sign out and a new Desktop & Documents folder gets created, what happens to my local files in the current one? That seems scary.